# D3 - Indented Collapse Tree - with additional columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 is the natural fit for my data, but I have important columns of data to show next to each node in the tree view.

Is this possible?

For example:

{
 "name": "OSS Applications",
 "children": [
  {
     "name": "ELITE 3E",
     "someData": "Some Data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Elite 3E Mobile Gateway"},
      {"name": "Elite 3E Mobile Website"},
      {"name": "Elite 3E Mobile Application"}

```
 ]
},
{
 "name": "WESTLAW DOC & FORM BUILDER",
 "someData": "Some Data",
 "children": [
  {"name": "Cobalt Website WFB",      "someData": "Some Data",},
  {"name": "Cobalt Static Content WFB"},
  {"name": "Cobalt Search WFA"},
  {"name": "Cobalt Forms Assembly WFB"},
  {"name": "Cobalt Foldering WFB"}
 ]
},
{
 "name": "FINDLAW.COM",
 "someData": "Some Data",
 "children": [
  {"name": "Findlaw-Infirmation",      "someData": "Some Data",},
  {"name": "Findlaw-hippocms"},
  {"name": "Findlaw-Lawyers Directory"},
  {"name": "Findlaw-ProfileUpdate"},
  {"name": "Findlaw-Pview"},
{"name": "Findlaw-RCMS"},
{"name": "Findlaw-public-channel"}
 ]
}
```

]
}

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Could you share some code for it? I'm quite lost on this whole thing. Do I need to create additional svg nodes? I want to display 3 additional columns of textual data.

Comment: The easiest is to add additional elements with classes that position them appropriately. You haven't told us what particular implementation you're using though.

Comment: var tree = d3.layout.tree() -- ah ok. If you could show me how? I could pattern match my way to add more.

Comment: Well the basic idea is that instead of adding a `text` element straight away, you add a `g` element that can then contain several text elements with appropriate positioning.

Comment: FYI, I want to convert this exact Protovis thing to D3 -- http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/indent.html

Comment: Something like [this](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/indentedtree.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff :  The link was broken, I guess you meant [this example](http://nvd3.org/examples/indentedtree.html)

Comment: @leoh Honestly can't remember what I intended to link to there, but looks relevant.